# How to enforce a rule on terms that are a combination of the original term?

Tags: rule

I have an equation of the type

```
Exp[a[r]] + Exp[a[r]/2] + Exp[-a[r]]
```

And I want to rule

```
Exp[a[r]] -> 1-2*m[r]/r
```

so that it fits the other terms as well. How can I do this directly?

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes. ```a[r]``` is any function of r

Comment: You haven't resolved the issue. `Exp` has a predefined meaning. If it is intended to be a user-defined symbol then use some other symbol. Otherwise, you presumably mean either `Exp[a[r]]` or `E^(a[r])` (they are equivalent).

Comment: And on the RHS of the rule, do you mean `1 - 2*m[r]/2` as shown (which is just `1 - m[r]`) or did you intend `(1 - 2*m[r])/2`

Comment: Sorry, I was using the python language. I made the changes you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Keep the LHS of rules as simple as possible

```
expr = Exp[a[r]] + Exp[a[r]/2] + Exp[-a[r]];

expr /. a[r] -> Log[1 - 2*m[r]/r] // Simplify

(* 1 + r/(r - 2 m[r]) - (2 m[r])/r + Sqrt[1 - (2 m[r])/r] *)
```